# Wildcard domains on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

How can I use wildcard domain on Heroku? My application is using subdomain.

I followed the Heroku custom domain article and mapped my `*.mydomain.com` to `myapp.herokuapp.com`. When I visit `dev.mydomain.com` it points to heroku app but on Heroku app I cant find the subdomain.

In short I want to use subdomain on heroku, like `dev.myapp.herokuapp.com`. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The wildcard setup on Heroku instructs Heroku to point any request for a subdomain of given domain to your application.

But here stops Heroku responsibility. Then your application must be able to handle such requests at application level.

In Rails, you can inspect the request details with the `request` object in your controller. And you can access the specific subdomain with `request.subdomain`.

So, for example, if you added `*.example.com` and someone access `foo.example.com`, the request object will respond with the following values:

```
request.host
# => foo.example.com
request.subdomain
# => foo
```

Now it's your responsibility to use such information in your app according to what you are trying to achieve.