# Route all subdomains to my Heroku Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, dns

I register my domains with DNSimple. My app is hosted on Heroku.

How can I arbitrarily route all subdomains to my Heroku app?

Example

- bluejays.cappedin.com
- redsox.cappedin.com
- anything.cappedin.com

No matter what the user types as the subdomain (always just 1 level deep) I want it routed to my heroku app. Ideally I don't want to *define* every single subdomain in Heroku or DNSimple... it should just direct everything.

Any and all subdomains are just routed to my app where I handle the logic of what to do with `request.subdomain` method.

Will having these "foul" up what I am trying to do (below)
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wildcard domains on heroku](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15024578/wildcard-domains-on-heroku)

Comment: @JonathanAllard That link has some info but it doesn't explain how to 1. Send all subdomains to my Heroku app 2. How to set up Heroku to accept all subdomains for my app

Comment: Okay, you're right, the answer over there could be more clear. I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In DNS setups, there are usually two parts to the equation: (1) the sending side, which is the DNS server that will direct the traffic to the server, and (2) the receiving side, which is the server being sent the traffic to, that often needs to know on which domains to listen.

The Heroku documentation on [Wildcard domains](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#add-a-wildcard-domain) is pretty clear:

> Add a wildcard domain to your app as you would with any other domain, but use the `*` wildcard subdomain notation.
>
> ```
> $ heroku domains:add *.example.com
> Adding *.example.com to example... done
> ```

The Heroku router is ready to receive your traffic. You just need to have your DNS point there. So, in your DNS—probably hosted at your registrar in your case—add your [wildcard record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_DNS_record):

```
*.example.com.  CNAME   example-1234.herokuapp.com
```

(or whatever Heroku tells you to put as CNAME)

Comment: I added an image. Will adding the * catch all the "previously undefined" cnames. Example I want the mail CNAME to remain but the others could go away if needed.

Comment: That would be the subject of another question, but it seems from reading the linked wiki article on [Wildcard DNS record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_DNS_record#Example_usages) that the wildcard would indeed catch only what's undefined.

Comment: Well written answer. Thank you so much.

Comment: working great. see example.cappedIn.com - all subdomains being redirected now. Now I just have to handle them in my Rails app. Thx.